# Dividing elements in one array by elements in other?

Tags: javascript

Maybe trivial but what is an elegant way of dividing elements in one array by another (assume arrays are of equal length)? For instance

```
var A = [2,6,12,18]
var B = [2,3,4,6]
```

Dividing should give me: `[1,2,3,3]`

Comment: Wishing JavaScript had a built in zip method, eh? :-)

Comment: @RayToal: :) Some habits are not dying no matter what!

Comment: Oh, I figured my solution was trivial enough. :P

Comment: @WaynnLue: Well... I really am looking for something fancy though I will accept yours if nothing else comes up :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have ES5 support, this may be a good option:

```
var result = A.map(function(n, i) { return n / B[i]; });
```

Where `n` in callback represents the iterated number in `A` and `i` is the index of `n` in `A`.

Comment: The [map from ecma5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.19), [map from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array examples](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/ECMAScript5Array/Default.html) from Microoft. Just as additional information. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the two arrays are always the same length:

```
var C = [];
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  C.push(A[i] / B[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any elegant method per se, as in one which avoids a forloop with a neat trick. There are some methods using `map()` which have already been listed. Those end up using a (longer) forloop, but they're smaller pieces of code. Otherwise, use this:

```
 var C= new Array(A.length)
 for(i=0;i<A.length;i++){
  C[i]=A[i]/B[i];
 }
```

Comment: @Bakudan Aah, I see what you mean.

Comment: Eeeck.  You should never iterate arrays with `for (i in A)`.  That retrieves properties of objects and can return things other than array elements.

Comment: @jfriend00: Actually that's my pet peeve as well. I sort of got lazy over here =P

Comment: What do you mean when you say the `for` loop would be "longer"?

Comment: @gilly3 I tested it out with a huge array, the above forloop was faster than map (which presumably contains a forloop and some other stuff). Though since its a built in function, I'd expect it to be faster. :/

Comment: @Manishearth where you have tested it? If you want to really test a script go to http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @Bakudan - Funny, I did just that: http://jsperf.com/divide-two-arrays. Besides comparing `for` loops against `.map()`, I also looked at the differences between `new Array(len)` vs `new Array()` vs `[]`. The results are very interesting.  I was most amused to see that Firefox's native implementation of `.map()` performs worse than than a JavaScript implementation, especially since I got the JavaScript implementation from [Firefox's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility). Here's a chart of my results: http://imgur.com/a/kDh3O#I5Xmy

Comment: @gilly3: Thanks for that =D. Wait... FF is _slower_ than IE? All my dreams...shattered... (I sort of abandoned FF for chrome but I still love it..). `new Array(len)/c.push(val)` seems awesome though!

Answer (score 2):

If you consider changing the Array prototype an option:

```
Array.prototype.zip = function (other, reduce, thisArg) {
  var i, result = [], args, 
      isfunc = typeof reduce == "function",
      l = Math.max(this.length, other.length);

  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    args = [ this[i], other[i] ];
    result.push( isfunc ? reduce.apply(thisArg, args) : args );
  }
  return result;
}

var A = [2,6,12,18]
var B = [2,3,4,6]
var C = A.zip(B, function (l, r) { return l / r; });
// -> [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: What about adding an optional 3rd parameter to specify the value of `this` to be used in the `reduce` function? That would be consistent with other Array iterator methods that take a function argument.

Comment: @gilly3 Absolutely. I'll change the function.